# Integral of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate mass of some line and this is the integral needed to be solved. 
Wolfram shows me some way with the fuction sec and reduction methods and I don't know how to use these. is there any other way that I miss?

$$\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}dt$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $t=\dfrac ab\tan\theta\;\Rightarrow\;dt=\dfrac ab\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$, the integral turns out to be
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}\ dt&=\int\sqrt{a^2+a^2\tan^2\theta}\cdot\dfrac ab\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}b\int\sec^3\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}\ d\theta\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos^4\theta}\ d\theta\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^2}\ d\theta.
\end{align}
$$
Now, let $u=\sin\theta\;\Rightarrow\;du=\cos\theta\ d\theta$, then
$$
\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^2}\ d\theta=\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}\ du.
$$
The last integral admits a decomposition by partial fractions:
$$
\dfrac {a^2}b\int\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}\ du=\dfrac {a^2}{4b}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}+\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}\right)\ du
$$
Integrating term-by-term, we will obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}\ dt&=\dfrac {a^2}{4b}\left(\ln\left|\frac{1+\sin \theta}{1-\sin \theta}\right|+2\sec \theta\tan \theta\right)+C\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}{4b}\left(\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}+bt}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}-bt}\right|+\frac{2bt\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}}{a^2}\right)+C\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}{4b}\left(\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}+bt}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}+bt}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}+bt}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}-bt}\right|+\frac{2bt\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}}{a^2}\right)+C\\
&=\dfrac {a^2}{2b}\left(\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}+bt}{a}\right|+\frac{bt\sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}}{a^2}\right)+C.\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can also use IBP to evaluate $\displaystyle\int\sec^3\theta$ by taking $u=\sec\theta$ and $dv=\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use a hyperbolic trig sub. Sub $\frac{bt}{a} = \sinh x.$

The circular trig sub $\frac{bt}{a} = \tan x$ would involve the integral of $\sec^3 x.$ Not that trivial, although doable.